# How to allow certain IP set resource with my WAF v2 via cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

example contrived for this question, based on the aws documentation, I I defined a WAFv2 resource type, a rule and IP set list by using WAF. the following works and it blocks the IP , i specified but how to allow certain IP list and block all others?

```
Resources:
  
  WebAcl:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      Name: sample-acl
      Scope: REGIONAL
      Description: sample ACL.
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {}
      VisibilityConfig:
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        MetricName: sample-acl
      Rules:
      - Name: blockIPList
        Priority: 4
        Action:
          Block: {}
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
          MetricName: IPListMetric
        Statement:
          IPSetReferenceStatement:
            Arn: !GetAtt myIPSet.Arn
 myIPSet:
    Type: 'AWS::WAFv2::IPSet'
    Properties:
      Name: sampleIPlistIPv4
      Scope: REGIONAL
      IPAddressVersion: IPV4
      Addresses:
        - 70.25.14.172/32
```

Comment: Can you provide link to the docs you followed? Also it is not really clear what you want to do. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Marcin - thanks. I want to block/allow IP list via WAF. I followed aws documentation on WAF v2 and created a WAF resource now i want to define a rule to block/allow IP list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable it on a CloudFront distribution

```
CloudFront:
Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    WebACLId: !GetAtt ExampleWebACL.Arn
```

Or for an ALB or API Gateway you can use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webaclassociation.html

```
Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation
Properties: 
  ResourceArn: String
  WebACLArn: String
```

Edit:
Did you perhaps mean how you enable you IPSet in your rule group?

```
RuleGroup:
Type: 'AWS::WAFv2::RuleGroup'
Properties:
  Name: SampleRuleGroup
  Scope: REGIONAL
  Description: SampleRuleGroup
  VisibilityConfig:
    SampledRequestsEnabled: true
    CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
    MetricName: SampleRuleGroupMetrics
  Rules:
    - Name: ip-whitelist
      Priority: 0
      Action:
        Allow: { }
      VisibilityConfig:
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        MetricName: ip-whitelist-metric
      Statement:
        IPSetReferenceStatement:
          Arn: !GetAtt SampleIPSet.Arn
```

Comment: thanks. is there a standard template to block sql injection or xss attack using waf , similar to what we have for blocking IP set? if you know of examples , let me know

Comment: Yes, AWS provides some managed rules for this. You can find them thru the console under Rules for your WebACL, just click add rules then "add managed rule groups" and look under AWS managed rule groups. You can probably find more rule groups in the market place. Read more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/aws-managed-rule-groups-list.html

Comment: one other thing i had to do , to make it work was for WAF -> default action : Block {} , then under the individual rule to allow the ip set , i put action: allow{}. the way i understand it is , by default it is going to block all requests, but only allow the ones i put it under the allow rule. trying to make sure, it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Well it all comes down to your use case, If you only want to allow a few specific ip's from your IPSet and block everything else then yes, you tell waf to block everything by default and then tell the ipset to allow traffic from your ip's.

Comment: this was helpful, thank you!  I find it interesting that this is actually quite different than the wafv2 console configuration, which is what was confusing me.