# how can i create and update WAF IPset using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-waf

I need to create A WAF IP SET using Cloud formation

I tried of writting  a stack template but its unable to create IP Set

Comment: What is your template? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

[AWS CloudFormation WAFv2 IPSet Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-ipset.html)

Here is an example from a Cloudformation WAF deployment I created.
It works well.

```
Resources:
  WAFblockIPSet:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::IPSet
    Properties: 
      Addresses: 
      - 255.255.255.255/32
      Description: blocking IPs that dont belong
      IPAddressVersion: IPV4
      Name: BlockIPSet
      Scope: REGIONAL

Outputs:
  myWAFBlockIPSet:
    Description:   IPSet creation
    Value: !GetAtt WAFblockIPSet.Arn
    Export:
      Name: MySharedServicesWAFBlockIPSetARN
```

After you export your IPSet arn, you will utilize that in your CloudFormation WebACL Stack :-)

[Good example of the webacl & IPSet in CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69186468/how-to-allow-certain-ip-set-resource-with-my-waf-v2-via-cloudformation)

Hope this helps!